# Why is there an unnecessary padding?

Tags: css

```html
<div style="background-color: #EEEEEE; display: inline-table;">
  <div style="display: inline-table;  width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; height: 5px;"><img src="/design/_messages/frame00.gif"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; height: 5px; background-image: url('/design/_messages/frameUP.gif');"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; height: 5px;"><img src="/design/_messages/frame01.gif"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-table; width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; background-image: url('/design/_messages/frameLEFT.gif');"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none">sdfkl sdklf jklfff ffff fff fff fffffsjdf klsfffff fff fjdf</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: right; width: 5px; background-image: url('/design/_messages/frameRIGHT.gif');"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-table;  width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; height: 5px;"><img src="/design/_messages/frame10.gif"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; height: 5px; background-image: url('/design/_messages/frameDOWN.gif');"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; height: 5px;"><img src="/design/_messages/frame11.gif"></div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lsroqeyg/

there is an unneccesary spacing at the right. The right edge is too far. See the image:
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: here is the problem: https://i.imgur.com/xIVqyo6.gif the whole thing must be as width as the length of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the display of the parent element to inline-grid as shown below

```html
<div style="background-color: #EEEEEE; display: inline-grid;"> <!--inline-grid here-->
  <div style="display: inline-table;  width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; height: 5px;"><img src="/design/_messages/frame00.gif"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; height: 5px; background-image: url('/design/_messages/frameUP.gif');"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; height: 5px;"><img src="/design/_messages/frame01.gif"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-table; width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; background-image: url('/design/_messages/frameLEFT.gif');"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none">sdfkl sdklf jklfff ffff fff fff fffffsjdf klsfffff fff fjdf</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: right; width: 5px; background-image: url('/design/_messages/frameRIGHT.gif');"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-table;  width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; height: 5px;"><img src="/design/_messages/frame10.gif"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; height: 5px; background-image: url('/design/_messages/frameDOWN.gif');"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 5px; height: 5px;"><img src="/design/_messages/frame11.gif"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Its new, but it fixes your problem https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/